# Setting/changing ValueType for a bounded DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have such XML string:

```
    xmlstring =
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" &
        "<ArrayOfMyData xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>" &
        "  <MyData>" &
        "    <ID>80</ID>" &
        "    <MyDate>2019-08-07T07:15:32.123</MyDate>" &
        "    <MyBool>true</MyBool>" &
        "  </MyData>" &
        "  <MyData>" &
        "    <ID>1</ID>" &
        "    <MyDate>2019-10-16T14:23:23.654</MyDate>" &
        "    <MyBool>false</MyBool>" &
        "  </MyData>" &
        "  <MyData>" &
        "    <ID>203</ID>" &
        "    <MyDate>2019-10-25T11:02:26.789</MyDate>" &
        "    <MyBool>false</MyBool>" &
        "  </MyData>" &
        "</ArrayOfMyData>"
```

Then I load it automatically to DataGridView:

```
        Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
        dataSet.ReadXml(New StringReader(xmlstring))
        dgv_list.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
```

And that is going very well.
DataGridView generate automatically columns and rows what is visible in fast populated grid.
But problem is that columns are of type `string, string, string` while I would like `integer, date, boolean` because of (re)sorting purposes.
As an alternative I know a way for creatnig/setup columns "manually", then fill a DGV cell by cell/row by row.

What interesting me is if here exists any trick/solution to change value type of columns in showed case to preserve maximal level of automation?
I try to change columns ValueType under `_ColumnAdded` handler, change written data under `_CellFormating` event handler and much more. But everything without any wanted result.

Please help!

Comment: Create a new `DataTable`, add new `DataColumn` of the required types (Interger, Date, Boolean), copy the rows from table(0) to the new data table, and bind it to the DGV.

Comment: I tested that. Interesting and usable. But I hope there is one more generic way.

Comment: Well, using XmlSerialization instead to serialize/desalinize `MyData` objects could be a way. Please check these [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074005/saving-listbox-with-additional-information-in-my-settings/59097544#59097544) and [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686509/trouble-serializing-and-deserializing-multiple-objects/58687570#58687570) posts. Might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the schema of types in your XML then reading that with `.XmlReadMode.ReadSchema`.
Doing that the column types  have the same type.
As a test put this xml in a file somewhere `“C:\Users\Principal\Documents\OtherPath\Test.xml”`  instead of a variable in your code.
The part of types is  `xs:schema`

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ArrayOfMyData>


  <xs:schema id="ArrayOfMyData" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="ArrayOfMyData" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">

          <xs:element name="MyData">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MyDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MyBool" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>

        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>



  <MyData>
    <ID>80</ID>
    <MyDate>2019-08-07T07:15:32.123+02:00</MyDate>
    <MyBool>true</MyBool>
  </MyData>

  <MyData>
    <ID>23</ID>
    <MyDate>2019-08-05T07:15:32.123+02:00</MyDate>
    <MyBool>false</MyBool>
  </MyData>

</ArrayOfMyData>
```

Then read with Schema types

```
 Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
 dataSet.ReadXml("C:\Users\Principal\Documents\OtherPath\Test.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)
```

Or

```
 Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
 Dim xmlS As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Principal\Documents\OtherPath\Test.xml")
 dataSet.ReadXml(New StringReader(xmlS), XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)
```

Also you can save your XML as a file with Schema

```
dataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema
dataSet.WriteXml("C:\Users\Principal\Documents\OtherPath\Test.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
```

Comment: Well, this is not asnwer in direction of simplicity but is valuable in mean of educational purposes. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to keep schema definitions in separate file since I have not influence in creating this XML and how that would look like?

Comment: Every thing is possible. I don’t know how much is convenient this, but with string concatenation, paying attention in names of tables and columns you can do that. My advice: don’t use separately.

Comment: I getting those original (more complicated) xml's by webrequests. So I would need to inject those schema in every xml before reading it. That sounds a bit overkilling to me. Plus (minus) I would not have original xml after this except I copy it before.

Comment: If you know the table names, column names and types I say yes. Work on <xs:schema adding <xs:element block for every table with types then put all together after your root tag (as example above shows) with string concatenation.